# LINQ query with GroupBy causing "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'..."

Tags: c#, linq, igrouping

I tried searching on this, but can't seem to find anything that matches my LINQ query to use to help me figure this one out.

I'm getting a message in the debugger in the Results View->base object

> +base {"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'.
>   Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this
>   context."}    System.SystemException {System.NotSupportedException}

Here is my LINQ query (that returns a result fine in LINQPad...):

```
public IEnumerable<PendingItems> GetHazmatPendingShipping()
{
    var pending = context.HazmatInfoes
                         .Where(h => (h.ShippingFlag.Equals(false) && (h.ShippingType.Equals("Manual"))))
                         .GroupBy(x => new {x.ToBU, x.FromBU}, y => new {y})
                         .Select(p => p);
    return pending;
}
```

I know my return type is wrong.  Will work on that after I figure out why this query fails to return a result.

**My answer to this problem:**

Since I had a key that was composite {string, string}, I had to create a class called PendingItems.

```
public IQueryable<PendingItems> GetHazmatPendingShipping()
    {
        IQueryable<PendingItems> pending = context.HazmatInfoes
            .Where(h => ((h.ShippingFlag.Value == false && h.ShippingType.Equals("Manual"))))
            .GroupBy(x => new {x.ToBU, x.FromBU}, y => y)
            .Select(p => new PendingItems {ToBu = p.Key.ToBU, FromBu = p.Key.FromBU, Items = p});
        return pending;
    }
```

The PendingItems class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Hazmat.Models
{
    public class PendingItems : IEnumerable
    {
        public string ToBu { get; set; }
        public string FromBu { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HazmatInfo> Items { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return this.Items;           
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Tim

P.S.  This answer helped with this problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1775514/2733668

Comment: looks like `LINQPad` sucks?

Comment: Given that your return type is wrong the code shouldn't *compile*, so how are you getting a runtime error through the debugger?

Comment: I don't know why you said this works in `LINQPad` but your query has something wrong

Comment: @McGarnagle isn't that we can practice `LINQ-to-SQL/EF` with `LINQPad`?

Comment: Here is the exact LINQPad query that works for me:  `HazmatInfo.Where(h => (h.ShippingFlag.Equals(false) && (h.ShippingType.Equals("Manual"))))
                .GroupBy(x => new {x.ToBU, x.FromBU}, y => new {y})
                .Select(p => p)`

Comment: @Servy, I have my return type in my code returning a new List<PendingItems> so it compiles.  I put a break there to look at my pending object to see why it was null.  I know the return type here is wrong, but that's what I want to return ultimately.

Comment: @McGarnagle, I am using EF with this project...  I'm hoping this works with EF also.  It would save a lot of headache/time.

Comment: @CooperT `pending` is not an `IEnumerable<PendingItems>` though, it's an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<SomeAnonymousType, SomeOtherAnonymousType>>`.

Comment: @Servy, it gives a result of `IEnumerable<IGrouping<{string,string}, HazmatInfo>>`.  But doesn't seem to like that format for the return type declaration.

Comment: @CooperT your `.Select(p=>p)` is redundant, your query obviously returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping...>`

Comment: @CooperT Yes, it's an entirely different type.  Given that it, won't compile.  Since it won't compile, discussing what it would do when run is rather pointless, since it *can't* run.

Comment: I doubt that the actual return type is `IQueryable<IGrouping...>`?

Comment: Ok, then can you help me GET IT TO RUN?

Comment: @CooperT oh, sorry - you're right.

Comment: y => new {y} ? try y => y or just remove that

Comment: What are the data types of `ShippingFlag` and `ShippingType`? I think at least one of them does not match the type in the `Equals` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when there is condition regarding `Nullable<>` field, and comparison doesn't reflect that. Then primitive (`false` in your case) is converted to `Nullable<>` object, and exception is raised.

Probably `ShippingFlag` is of type `Nullable<bool>`, and assuming that you should rewrite your condition like this:

```
var pending = context.HazmatInfoes
    .Where(h => (!h.ShippingFlag.HasValue && h.ShippingFlag.Value.Equals(false)) && h.ShippingType.Equals("Manual"))
```

Comment: ShippingFlag is a nullable type.  I've queried only on `h.ShippingType.Equals("Manual")` and I've gotten valid results.  So it does seem to be `ShippingFlag` that is causing the issue.  I tried your addition to the query and it still fails and I get the same error of `Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`  The query returns valid results if I add `h.ShippingFlag.HasValue` but remove `h.ShippingFlag.Equals`.  Thanks for the insight, at least we've now narrowed it down.

Comment: Make sure you call `h.ShippingFlag.Value.Equals` not `h.ShippingFlag.Equals`. `HasValue` is only checking for NULL.

Comment: Needed to change `h.ShippingFlag.Equals(false)` to `h.ShippingFlag.Value == false`.  I should have known better as I've queried on that before that way!  Thanks for the help!  Now to figure how to declare the proper return type.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It saved me a lot of time. Btw: I got a nullable Guid and 'guid.Value.Equals' is still causing an error but 'guid.Value ==' is working. Maybe this helps others.